# Angular: Print result of method expression

Tags: angular

I am trying to export common HTML structures (like a bootstrap navbar) into Angular components. Here is my components HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{navBarTitle}}</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li *ngFor="let item of navBarItems">
        <a href="#">{{item.display()}}</a> <!-- The Problem is here -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the component class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() private navBarTitle: string = "Klassenliste";
  @Input() private navBarItems: Clazz[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The usage looks like this:

```
<bs-navbar
  navBarTitle="Classes"
  [navBarItems]="classes">
</bs-navbar>
```

An important thing to note is that the `classes` array is being fetched from
a server in `ngOnInit()` using the `HttpModule`.

```
this.getClasses()    // returns an Observable<Clazz[]>
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(` * ERROR * : ${error}`);
        throw new Error(error);
      })
      .subscribe((clazzes: Clazz[]) => {
        console.log(`Fetched classes`);
        console.log(clazzes);
        this.classes = clazzes;
      });
  private getClasses(): Observable<Clazz[]> {
    return this.http
      .get("/api/classes")
      .map(response => response.json() as Clazz[]);
  }
```

The items in the collection `navBarItems` do implement the `display` method:

```
export class Clazz { // Edited to "Clazz", just in case
    id: number;
    name: string;

    // constructor etc.

    display(): string {
        if(this.name) {
            return this.name; 
        }
        return "---";
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, the `{{item.display()}}` call does not seem to return anything. The link just appears with empty text.
When I substitute the `{{item.display()}}` call with `{{item.name}}`, the name is displayed correctly. However I'd like this setup to work with any class that implements the `display()` method.

The console throws the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.display is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (BsNavbarComponent.html:8)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14727)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13841)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14119)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13842)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
```

Sorry if I am missing something obvious here, I am kind of new to Angular.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. Also "This being called "Class" shouldn't be a problem, right?" See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: Works fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh5xax. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did.

Comment: @JBNizet I think I forgot the most important bit. The classes are being fetched asynchronously. I will update my question now

Comment: You, once again, forgot the most important piece: the getClasses method.

Comment: @JBNizet That is because I strongly believe that it is not part of the problem. It doesn't do anything crazy: (adding the code above)

Comment: It's always important to provide complete code, even if you feel it's not important.  In this case it turns out the part you believe is not part of the problem is, in fact, part of the problem.

Comment: Incidentally if my answer does not fix the issue, please add a sample json output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply typecast a JSON object to a class[], as in:

```
response.json() as Clazz[]
```

.. you don't get all the class methods. It's only indicating to Typescript that the type is compatible. Remember that Typescript compiles down to JavaScript which doesn't allow you to directly parse json into a function or ES6 class.

You need to iterate over each item, instantiate a new instance of the class, and fill in the data from there.

Comment: Thank you, I found it really confusing that Typescript let me use these "Clazz" objects even though they're not really that, just some objects that **seem** like Clazz objects. I guess duck-typing is a feature that needs some getting used to.

Comment: Well, that's because you told Typescript that it IS one of those objects, even though it's not. It wouldn't know about the mismatch until runtime, but at that point it's just plain Javascript so it doesn't know/care about your types.